# boostrap z-index not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overlay, z-index

I want to build a homepage which will consist of 5 images, top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right and centered. The centered image has to be positioned slightly over the edges of the others. The margin-top: -80px solves this for the upper edges. However, the margin-bottom: -80px places the image below the others although his z-index is much higher.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8208/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container nopadding-mobile" >
    <div class="row hometiles" >
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="http://www.nigeltomm.com/images/green_square_nigel_tomm_m.jpg" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <img src="http://www.nigeltomm.com/images/green_square_nigel_tomm_m.jpg" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row hometiles" >
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <div class="logotile">
                <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg" width="100%" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row hometiles" >
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="http://www.nigeltomm.com/images/green_square_nigel_tomm_m.jpg" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
            <img src="http://www.nigeltomm.com/images/green_square_nigel_tomm_m.jpg" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code should always be posted on SO as well, even if you find jsfiddle nicer to use. One day, jsfiddle might not exist anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` only works on positioned elements, change it to `position:relative` and it will work.

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) on `z-index`

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8247/)

Comment: I +1 this one even doe I was one second earlier :D

Answer (score 2):

Actually its an easy solution.

You just have to give the image a position attribute because z-index only works on positioned elements.

```
.logotile{
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% + 80px);
    margin: -120px -40px -120px -40px;
    z-index: 314159;
}
```